# How to set min and max value of input control dynamically based on selection Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, input

I am looking for some generic solution to update min and max value dynamically based on dropdown selection. Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05Ldg6uv/2/).

If user select :

- **Hours** - min and max value should be 1 to 24
- **Minutes** - min and max value should be 60 to 6000
- **Seconds** - min and max value should be 3000 to 10000

I am looking for some solution which will update the binding at input control based on selection. Also it should update the validation message. Looking for some generic and reusable solution so It can be reused across application.

Here is my code:
**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="TimeController as vm">
    <label>Desired RPO</label>
    <div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="desiredRPO" min="minvalue" max="maxvalue" step="1" />
            <div class="input-group-btn" style="display:inline-block;">
                <select class="form-control">
                    <option>HOURS</option>
                    <option>MINUTES</option>
                    <option>SECONDS</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <span>Please enter value between {{minvalue}} and {{maxvalue}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TimeController', function($scope) {
    var vm = this;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See answer here [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/oQoahf2XsPsWDsPw5D4g?p=preview)

In your HTML

```
<div ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="TimeController as vm">
   <form  name="vm.timeForm" novalidate>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Please select</label>
        <select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.selectedOption" ng-change="vm.updateMinMax()">
            <option value="hours">HOURS</option>
            <option value="minutes">MINUTES</option>
            <option value="seconds">SECONDS</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : vm.timeForm.desiredRPO.$invalid && !vm.timeForm.desiredRPO.$pristine }">
        <label>Desired RPO</label>
        <input type="number" name="desiredRPO" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.desiredRPO" ng-min="vm.minValue" ng-max="vm.maxValue">
        <p ng-show="vm.timeForm.desiredRPO.$invalid" class="help-block">Please enter value between {{vm.minValue}} and {{vm.maxValue}}</p>
      </div>
   </form>
  </div>
```

In your controller

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TimeController', function($scope) {
   var vm = this;

   vm.timeForm = {};

   vm.updateMinMax = function() {
      if(vm.selectedOption === 'hours') {
         vm.minValue = 1;
         vm.maxValue = 24;
      } else if(vm.selectedOption === 'minutes') {
         vm.minValue = 60;
         vm.maxValue = 6000;
      } else {
         vm.minValue = 3000;
         vm.maxValue = 10000;
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Please check the plunkr... https://plnkr.co/edit/oQoahf2XsPsWDsPw5D4g?p=preview .. Design wise you can change it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your required answer, with a Fiddle

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TimeController', function($scope) {

  var vm = $scope;
  
  vm.update_values = function() {
      if(vm.selected === 'hours') {
         vm.min = "1";
         vm.max = "24";
      } else if(vm.selected === 'minutes') {
         vm.min = "60";
         vm.max = "6000";
      } else {
         vm.min = "3000";
         vm.max = "10000";
     }
   }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<style href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></style>

<div ng-app="app">

  <div ng-controller="TimeController">
    <label>Desired RPO</label>
    <div>
      <div class="input-group">

        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="desiredRPO" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" step="1" ng-model="time"/>
        

        <div class="input-group-btn" style="display:inline-block;">
          <select class="form-control" ng-change="update_values()" ng-model="selected">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="hours">HOURS</option>
            <option value="minutes">MINUTES</option>
            <option value="seconds">SECONDS</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <span>Please enter value between {{min}} and {{max}}</span>

    </div>
    <h3>Requirement:    </h3>
    <h4>
    If user select :
    Hours - min and max value should be 1 to 24 <br>
    Minutes - min and max value should be 60 to 6000 <br>
    Seconds - min and max value should be 3000 to 10000 <br>
    </h4>
    <h6>
    I am looking for some solution which will update the binding at input control based on selection. Also it should update the validation message.
    Looking for some generic and reusable solution so It can be reused across application.
    </h6>
  </div>
```

**Pls run the code and check**

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/05Ldg6uv/6/)

Comment: Seen just now, But Pratik's answers looks more relevant. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

There are ng-min ng-max directives for dynamic values

```
<input ng-min="vm.diapason.min" ng-max="vm.diapason.max"/>

<select class="form-control" ng-model="vm.diapason" 
             ng-options="option.label for option in vm.restrictions">
 </select>
```

and controller with

```
vm.restrictions = [
  {
    label: 'HOURS',
    min: 1,
    max: 24
  },
  {
    label: 'MINUTES',
    min: 60,
    max: 6000
  },
  {
    label: 'SECONDS',
    min: 3000,
    max: 10000
  }
]
```

Comment: how can we change them based on selection.. can u update fiddle?

Comment: I know this approach is different than other, but somehow I am not able to make it work using this approach. if possibel can u update this with ur appraoch https://plnkr.co/edit/oQoahf2XsPsWDsPw5D4g?p=preview

Comment: I mistake a litte with ng-value. You could engage with my approch using ng-options. will edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

i've just created a working Plunkr , hope it helps.

https://plnkr.co/edit/rCQzEhojZP0iHvoI1KlO?p=preview

INDEX.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">


    <div ng-controller="TimeController as vm">
      <label>Desired RPO</label>
      <div>
        <div ng-init="item=timings[0]" class="input-group">

          <input type="number" class="form-control" name="desiredRPO" min="{{item.min}}" max="{{item.max}}" step="1" />

          <div class="input-group-btn" style="display:inline-block;"> 

            <select
              ng-model="item" 
              ng-options="item.type for item in timings"></select>

          </div>
        </div>
        <span>Please enter value between {{item.min}} and {{item.max}}</span>

      </div>
      <h3>Requirement:    </h3>
      <h4>
      If user select :
      Hours - min and max value should be 1 to 24 <br>
      Minutes - min and max value should be 60 to 6000 <br>
      Seconds - min and max value should be 3000 to 10000 <br>
      </h4>
      <h6>
      I am looking for some solution which will update the binding at input control based on selection. Also it should update the validation message.
      Looking for some generic and reusable solution so It can be reused across application.
      </h6>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('TimeController', function($scope) {

var vm = this;
$scope.timings = [{type: 'HOURS', min: 1, max: 24}, 
{type: 'MINUTES', min: 60, max: 6000}, 
{type: 'SECONDS', min: 3000, max: 10000}];

});
```